# boto3 Determine Storage Size of Table in DynamoDB

Tags: python, boto3

I know how to get the item count, but is there a way to determine the storage size of a table programatically?

In the console when you look at "Overview" of a table you can see the "Storage Size (in bytes)", it is that number I am after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are asking for DynamoDb. You can try following:

```
from boto3 import resource
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

# The boto3 dynamoDB resource
dynamodb_resource = resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb_resource.Table(table_name)
bytes_size = table.table_size_bytes
```